# Windows command shell randomly prints block characters at output line endings

Tags: windows, command-line

In my command prompt in Windows 10 (new console), I frequently see random cursor characters rendered at the end of some lines, depending on the load in other tasks. I believe this is associated with output lines containing LF characters (rather than Windows' usual CRLF line endings). Has anybody else seen this? Is there a way to stop these random cursor characters from printing?

[image: Example output]

Comment: You're referring to the blocks at the ends of four of the lines?  If that related to the Linux/Windows difference in line termination, it should be the same on every line.

Comment: @fixer1234 — good point. I neglected to mention that I do not see this behavior in tools that emit CRLF line endings, only in tools that use LF only.

Comment: Have you tried copying lines with and without the blocks, and looking at the actual characters with a hex editor?

Comment: It's a visual artifact. If you select and copy, the marks disappear. Pasting the copied data anyways yield no additional actual character. (And I'm not sure what encoding that would be. UTF-8?) Interestingly, if I use the command-prompt copy of what I would assume to be CRLF text (the help output of the `dir` command), I still see only LF characters.

Comment: More interesting. If I select a character anywhere on a line with the cursor character at the end, the end mark disappears. Wait. Only sometimes. And some other times, selecting a character _after_ the mark on the same line erases the mark. Odd.